# Missing Text in iOS UIActivityViewController Cancel Button

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an iOS application written in Swift, and the Cancel button in my UIActivityViewController is missing its text.  The button is full white.
I've tried setting the tint, and title color of UIButton.appearance()
as well as setting a tint on the UIActivityViewController's view before presenting it.  Any ideas?

```
activityViewController = UIActivityViewController( activityItems: [ shareActivity ], applicationActivities: nil )
        activityViewController.setValue("subject", forKey:"subject" )
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivityTypePrint,
            UIActivityTypeAssignToContact
        ]

        if ( UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad )
        {
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.controller.view
        }
        controller.presentViewController( activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HdwzYfC.png works for me. Try running this code on a different device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my missing text was white text on the white background.  (You can see this by Debug View Hierarchy button while the controller is visible;  select the button and you can faintly see the outline of the text.)  I found that if you have set UILabel's textColor and/or UIButton's tintColor using appearances, it will affect UIAlertViewController.  Unfortunately, using appearance.whenContainedInInstancesOf: did not help.  I had to simply remove the appearance setting.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue:

```
UIView.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```

had been set to prevent large images from extending beyond the screen during transitions, and apparently that breaks the text on the buttons in UIAlertViews as well as UIActivityControllers.